# doesn't ohm's law applied to every thing?

Tags: power, voltage

I've read that voltage is high in step up transformer due to greater no. of turns it makes sense but why it reduce current?I have done a lot of search on it but there is only one answer.that is to make power constant.doesn't it violate ohm's law?
There is constant voltage of 220 is applied to our household appliances.it means current passes through them depend upon resistance of appliance.I have read that the resistance of a filament bulb is very high than simple energy saver bulb or LED.it means more current passes through energy saver or LED bulb then why power consumption of filament bulb is high than LED.
I am student of first semester in EE.my basic concept are vague which is headache to me.I do a lot of search.but very rear answer satisfy me

Comment: Transformer is a step-up or step-down device and their operation explained by a complex theory other than ohm'm law. For sure if you get the ohmic part of individual winding of the transformer out of this, then you can apply ohm's low, but this is meaningless even the use of the transformer is to match impedances (complex resistances).

Comment: Ohm's law is not violated, because the *primary winding* and *secondary winding* have *different* impedance (complex resistance): primary Vp = Zp * Ip; secondary Vs = Zs * Is. Secondary winding impedance Zs is related to primary winding impedance Zp by turns ratio Ns/Np and magnetic coupling factor (mutual inductance). Power is conserved (ideal transformer); Vp * Ip = Vs * Is.

Comment: Please try to rewrite your question with some formatting. [Line breaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) can **greatly** improve the readability.

Answer (score 4):

> doesn't ohm's law applied to every thing?

No, Ohm's law describes ohmic devices only.  From the Wikipedia article "[Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law#Resistive_circuits)":

> **An element (resistor or conductor) that behaves according to Ohm's law
>   over some operating range is referred to as an ohmic device**

But there are many devices that are not ohmic such as capacitors, inductors, and PN junctions to name just a few.  You will learn about these later in your studies.

> I've read that voltage is high in step up transformer due to greater
>   no. of turns it makes sense but why it reduce current?

A transformer is not an amplifier; it cannot increase the power.  Ideally, there is no power loss (practically, there must be some loss).

But power is the product of the voltage and associated current.

$$p = v \cdot i $$

Thus, if the secondary voltage is greater than the primary voltage, the secondary current must be less than the primary current in precisely the right proportion such that the primary and secondary powers are equal:

$$v_P \cdot i_P = v_S \cdot i_S$$

or

$$\frac{v_S}{v_P} = \frac{i_P}{i_S}$$

For example, if the secondary voltage is twice the primary voltage, the secondary current is half the primary current.

Answer (score 2):

Ohm's law specifically deals with the relationship between direct voltage, current and linear resistance in the form V = IR. For AC circuits it can be generalised to V =IZ where Z is a complex impedance.

Transformers convert an alternating primary *current* into an alternating magnetic field in the core which is then converted back to an alternating *voltage* in the secondary coil - This effect was demonstrated by Michael Faraday. (*Google* Faraday, transformer) He showed that the input and output voltages where connected by the turns ratio. For a 100% efficient transformer we get:

```
                  Vin  = N * Vout    (where N is turns ratio input to output)

                  Iout = N * Iin
```

We must also apply the conservation of energy rule - **you can't get more out than you put in**. Given that there will always be a loss of energy (heat, noise etc.) the power output will always be less than the power input. 
always greater
                      Iin * Vin > Iout * Vout  (Power in is always greater than power out)

If a load is connected to the secondary coil a current will flow. The transformer will react by increasing the primary current in line with the transformer turns ratio in order to maintain the power in to power out relationship.

*A filament bulb* works by heating the filament to a high temperature. Most of the energy used is radiated as **heat** rather than light, making this type of bulb inefficient. The colour of the light is determined by temperature. (*Google* black body radiation, Stefan-Boltzmann law).

*'Energy saver' bulb*s use a gas discharge lamp and phosphor coatings to produce light. (*Google* - Electric discharge in gases) The current passing through the reduced pressure gas excites electrons directly which then  jump from one energy band to another before decaying and emitting a photon. (*Google* - Planck-Einstein relationship) This means that they generate light energy directly without the need to generate lots of heat energy. This makes them more energy efficient that filament bulbs for the same power input. Hence the term 'energy saver.'

*LED lights* (Google band gap, LED) use a similar principle (electrons jumping from one level to another) through a PN junction in a semiconductor.This is more efficient than gas discharge lamps giving LED lighting more lumens (light output) per watt.

Answer (score 1):

Ohm's law only applies to linear resistors (or more generally, to linear impedances).

Ideal transformers are not resistors or linear impedances; therefore they can't be modeled accurately using Ohm's Law.

Answer (score 1):

Ohm's Law applies to DC circuits.
It can also apply to AC circuits if the circuit has purely resistive elements.

But in the real world, there are a lot of circuit elements that tend to act inductively or capacitively.

An inductor will tend to store energy in a magnetic field.
This makes it resist changes in current.

A capacitor will tend to store electrons as an electric charge.
This makes it resist changes in voltage.

When a AC circuit has a transformer in it, the primary is storing energy in iron core that is translated back to electricity in the secondary. 
Assuming an ideal transformer with no losses, where 220VAC at 1 amp enters the primary; we have 220 volt amperes doing work on the primary.
If the secondary is 22volts, it should be able to feed 10 Amps.
And the turns ratio from primary to secondary would be 10 to 1 (220 to 22)
Also the wire gauge would have to be sized to be able to carry the current on each side. And the core that the windings are wound upon would have to be able to store enough magnetic field energy to allow the transfer to take place.

You can think of a transformer as being the electrical equivalent to a belt and pulley system. If a large pulley and a small pulley are connected by a belt then the small pulley will have a high RPM and low torque, while the the large pulley has a low rpm and high torque. Torque or force makes the wheels turn and RPM measures how much movement occurs. Voltage is the force that makes electrons move and current is the measure of how much movement happens.

Comment: Ohm's law applies to complex impedances (capacitive, inductive) as well as pure resistances.

Comment: @PkP Ohm's law, in the strict sense, applies only to devices in which the current through them is proportional to the voltage across them over a wide range of currents. The ratio of voltage to current is then defined as the resistance. In reality, most devices are non-linear to some extent so Ohm's law is more theoretical than real.

Comment: @Barry Hmm, one could also argue that Ohm's law, in the strictest sense, applies only to metal conductors, as Ohm's law is written as "The Resistance of a Metal Conductor is Constant in a Constant Temperature" and all this "U=RI" formulae has been written since then. U=RI is a generalization of Ohm's law and U=ZI is a further generalization. Why stop at U=RI and not take the step to U=ZI? Why not explore the whole relationship of voltage vs. current instead of just one aspect.